# Exercise 0.6 in Algebra by Roger Godement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $R,S$ be two relations and $x$ a letter not contained in $R$. Show that
the relation
$$
(\forall x)(R \lor S) \iff (R \lor (\forall x)S)
$$
is true.

I am just working on the "$\Rightarrow$" case for this question.

I can rearrange the original expression using some rules of logic (provided in
the book) and then I end up using a
truth table to get the answer. I think Godement just wants me to use the rules of logic he has provided
rather than resorting to a truth table. If you answer this question then such
rules of logic will probably be quite obvious to you since you are not a
beginner like me and so I won't quote them from the book here.

(*Thanks @DavidDiaz for the table formatting edit*)

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 R & S &\lnot S & (\exists x)(\lnot S)\quad (*) & R \lor \lnot[(\exists x)(\lnot S)] \lor [(\exists x)(\lnot R) \land (\exists x)(\lnot S)] \\ \hline
F & F & T & T & T \\ \hline
F & T & F & T & T \\ \hline
T & F & T & T & T\\ \hline
T & T & F & T & T \\ \hline
\end{array}
(*) Note that, and I may be abusing truth tables here, I notice that there
exists at least one T value in the $(\lnot S)$ column, so I can say that the $(\exists
x)(\lnot S)$ column is true for all rows [1]. I use a similar approach on the last column. In the interest of keeping the table reasonable in
size I've not included some of the columns I used.

1. Granting that my use of a truth table is an inelegant way to prove
   this, can you tell me if what I did, in [1] above, is logically correct and a valid use of the truth table? Update: This is a fine, though inelegant approach, see my answer below for a useful reference that settles this question.
2. More importantly, can you show me how to do this the proper way using only
   rules of logic and no explicit truth table (as I am sure Godement intends)? Update: See my, and hopefully others, answer(s) below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the edit (once approved) to ensure it matched your intended table. For future reference mathjax tables are well described here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/how-can-i-put-a-table-here

Comment: Thanks for the table edit @DavidDiaz and the reference for tables.

Comment: @quasi, thanks for the feedback. Am I to understand (which makes sense) that $(\forall x)S$ is logically equivalent to $S$? If so, then I agree. Are we missing a step(s) though in getting from $(\forall x)S$ to $S$ at this beginner level that the book is presenting? The reason I ask is that Godement goes on a bit about quantifiers at a low level. Sorry I don't know a better way to say it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Let me revise my earlier comment. If $x$ is a letter not contained in $P$, then $(\forall x)P\iff P$.

Comment: Yes, for $R$ that is true, i.e., $x$ is not contained in $R$. But $x$ is contained in $S$, so I am not yet sure how I'd get from $R \lor (\forall x)S \iff R \lor S$ in your comment above. My knowledge has a gap there.

Comment: What symbology do you have for $S$ with $x$ replaced by an arbitrary entity $c$ ? Often written as $[x\backslash c]S$, ${S\vert}^x_c$ or similar.  Then can you justify with your rules that:$$\forall x~R\vee S~{ \iff {(R\vee S)\vert}^x_c\\ \iff R\vee {S\vert}^x_c \\\iff R\vee \forall x~S}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, Godement uses symbology like $(\forall x)R \Rightarrow (A|x)R$ where $x$ is "a letter", $A$ is "a mathematical object". Actually this was my first exposure to thinking about what we are doing when we substitute mathematical objects for letters in a relation.

Comment: @Joe: My earlier comment (now deleted) was wrong. It was only true for $R$.

Comment: @quasi, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You can easily "format" Graham's proof into Godement's system.  From $(∀x)(R∨S)$ apply Subst rule page 30 to get $(A|x)(R∨S)$ and then $(A|x)R ∨ (A|x)S$. Then, using the comment (page 30) : "It goes without saying that if the letter $x$ does not appear at all in the assembly $R$, then the relation $(A | x)R$ is just $R$", to derive :  $R ∨ (A|x)S$.

Comment: The problem with Graham's proof is that Godement system has no rule to infer $∀x S$ from $(A|x)S$ (while "proof by cases" is simply rule (TL.6) page 29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prove "$\Rightarrow$" case:

At first attempt, we'd like to do the following:

$$
(\forall x)(R \lor S) \Rightarrow [(\forall x)R \lor (\forall x)S]
$$

Unfortunately,

$$
(\forall x)(R \lor S) \iff [(\forall x)R \lor (\forall x)S]
$$

is not true in general. [See Godement, p.33, (TL 10) discussion].

Starting again,

$$
(\forall x)(R \lor S) \Rightarrow (R \lor (\forall x)S)
$$

is equivalent to [because $(P \Rightarrow Q) \iff Q \lor \lnot P$ is a true relation - this is easy to miss: that by the foregoing rule the consequent has become the antecedent, no distribution of $(\forall x)$ has occurred across $(R \lor S)$]

$$
(R \lor (\forall x)S) \lor \lnot [(\forall x)(R \lor S)]
$$

which simplifies to

$$
(R \lor (\forall x)S) \lor (\exists x)(\lnot R \land \lnot S)
$$

Because $(\exists x)(P \land Q) \iff [(\exists x)P \land (\exists x)Q]$ is a true relation, we can simplify further to obtain

$$
(R \lor (\forall x)S) \lor [(\exists x)\lnot R \land (\exists x)\lnot S]
$$

Since $x$ is not contained in $R$, we now have (on the RHS)

$$
[R \lor (\forall x)S] \lor [\lnot R \land (\exists x) \lnot S]
$$

Since $[\lnot R \land (\exists x) \lnot S]$ is equivalent to $\lnot [R \lor (\forall x) S]$ we have

$$
[R \lor (\forall x)S] \lor \lnot [ R \lor (\forall x) S]
$$

but then we have a tautology.

The converse is yet to be proved as I have done all I want to do for today.

Regarding my original question part #1, I was subsequently able to satisfy myself that my use of the truth table, inelegant as it was, was in fact correct with respect to the existential, $\exists$, quantifiers. This was the helpful source that made that clear: [Truth Tables for Predicate Logic - G52DOA - Derivation of Algorithms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwju6rzh64ncAhWE0J8KHexeAiIQFgg_MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.nott.ac.uk%2F~pszvc%2Fg52doa%2Fpredicate_truth.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2pKyIPldeJ4Pw1wjfdaSbq)

Comment: I'm not sure that your "strategy" of proving the formula showing that it is equivalent to a tautology is the "right" style of proof of Godement's system. Having said that, the strategy will work if **every** step is based on an equivelence (bi-conditional). Now, for example, the step form $(∀x)S$ to $(A|x)S$ is not an equivalence (we lack in G's system of A "generalization rule" that, in any way, has restrictions).

Comment: IMO, the single quantifier axiom of G's system : (LA.5), is **not** enough. Comapre with e.g. Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA67), CRC Press (6th ed 2015), page 67. It is quite similar but it has the **Gen rule** as well as the following quantifier axiom : "$(∀x)(B ⇒C) ⇒ (B ⇒(∀x)C)$, if $B$ contains no free occurrences of $x$" that, written in G's form is exactly : $(∀x)(¬B ∨ C) ⇒ (¬B ∨ (∀x)C)$.

Comment: My "suspect" above is confirmed by [Bourbaki](https://books.google.it/books?id=7eclBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37) (quite surely the source of G's system): see page 37, rule "(C27). If $R$ is a theorem in a logical theory $\mathcal T$ in which the letter $x$ is not a constant, then $(∀x)R$ is a theorem in the theory $\mathcal T$."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for this. I am going to check out the helpful refs you provided. You are correct about G getting his system from Bourbaki. He says so and references Bourbaki's Elem.s of Mathematics (which undoubtedly is using similar/same material to the book you referenced). I am glad to get more refs as G did not prove, for instance, the implication (he didn't claim the equivalence) of $(\forall x)P \Rightarrow (A|x)P$. By the way, note that $(P \Rightarrow Q) \iff Q \lor \lnot P$. The $(R \lor (\forall x)S)$ didn't come from distributing the $(\forall x)$ across $(R \lor S)$.

Comment: I updated the proof. Now we have equivalences all the way down (and up). Though I think it now stands, I'd still like to see other ways to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

If $\forall x~R\vee S$ then for any arbitary entity (or "mathematical object"), $A$, we have $(A\mid x)(R\vee S)$, and therefore $((A\mid x)R)\vee((A\mid x)S)$.

In the case for $(A\mid x)R$ then since $x$ does not occur free in $R$, that would be just $R$ and hence $R\vee \forall x~ S$ can be inferred (via the rule of "disjunction introduction", or "weakening").

In the case for $(A\mid x)S$, then since $A$ is arbitrary, $\forall x~S$ and hence $R\vee\forall x~S$ can be inferred.

Therefore $R\vee\forall x~S$ can be inferred from $\forall x~(R\vee S)$ using "proof by cases".

---

The derivation for the converse is much the same.

Comment: Thank you. However, I worked this through rereading Godement and the step which assumes $(\forall x)(R \lor S) \iff (\forall x)R \lor (\forall x)S$ "is not in general true" in the words of Godement. So, apparently, there is still some work to do to prove this one. As a point of comparison, $(\forall x)(R \land S) \iff (\forall x)R \land (\forall x)S$ is true.

Comment: "is not in general true" should have read "is not true in general" in the above comment